# udp client bind

Tags: c#, sockets, udp, client, bind

I have UDP client chat, which sends messages to the server and get the responses back. I have two threads, one for sending, one for receiving messages. I get the exception with ReceiveFrom() method: "You must call the Bind method before performing this operation". But this is a client, I don't want to bind anything. For example this client works fine:

```
    byte[] data = new byte[30];
    string input, stringData;
    IPEndPoint servIPEP = new IPEndPoint(
            IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 9050);
    EndPoint servEP = (EndPoint)servIPEP;
    Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
            SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
    string welcome = "Hello, are you there?";
    data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(welcome);
    client.SendTo(data, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, servEP);
    data = new byte[30];
    int recv = client.ReceiveFrom(data, ref servEP);    //works fine!
```

There is no bind for receiving. But when I create two threads error is thrown:

```
 public ChatClient()
        {
            clientSock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, 
                               SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
            servIPEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 32000);
            servEP = (EndPoint)servIPEP;
        }

         public void ReceiveThread()
        {
            Thread receiveThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ReceiveData));
            receiveThread.Start();
        }

        public void ReceiveData()
        {
           while(true){
                clientSock.ReceiveFrom(buf, ref servEP); //Here I get ERROR
                string msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf).Trim();
                Console.WriteLine("New message: {0}",msg);
                }

        }

        public void SendThread()
        { 
            Thread sendThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(SendData));
            sendThread.Start();
        }

        public void SendData()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter message to send: ");
                string msg = Console.ReadLine();
                buf = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg);
                clientSock.SendTo(buf, servEP);
            }
        }
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        ChatClient client = new ChatClient();
        client.SendThread();
        client.ReceiveThread();
    }
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I found out that it works only if SendTo() was first, otherwise when ReceiveFrom() is first it's not working. Could someone explain why is it working only like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly SendTo() does an implicit bind, and ReceiveFrom() doesn't.

It doesn't make much sense to start receiving without a prior bind to at least set the port number you're receiving via. Otherwise how would you expect to get any data?

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that SendTo() does implicit bind, now it makes sense :)